# sifr recognising < a > tags when they are the root element

Tags: sifr

It doesn't seem like sIFR renders the text as a link when the tag you are replacing IS the < a > link instead of containing the link. Have I missed something or can this be added to the new version?

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sIFR replaces the *content* of the elements you specify. Therefore, it replaces the text *inside* the `<a>`, not the link itself. You need to replace the parent element of the link, such that the link itself ends up inside the Flash movie.

If necessary you can wrap the link in a `<span>` and replace the `<span>`.